# Can method in interface return type of "this"?

Tags: typescript

Example code:

```
interface IBuilder {
  build(): this; // Builder?
}

class Builder implements IBuilder {
  ...
  public build(): this {
    ...
    return this;
  }
}
```

Question in topic.

Will it work the same as if method returned type of Builder?

Comment: This shows how to achieve that using `type`, might be helpful to you: https://medium.com/@bensammons/building-a-fluent-interface-with-typescript-using-generics-in-typescript-3-4d206f00dba5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it doesn't work the way you intend it to, take a look at this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8CwAUMsgEYCuwANgCYAUAlAFzJgAWwAzgNxEC+RIgipxOnZACFKtaMmABbAA5UI8iOHEZseIiUXlSVYAjLT6zVh3EFiJZFAhhyUEJa69bAwl6Eixks2gAJjklFTUNNCwcGz0DIxMKanMWdi4dWxIHJxdkEAgAdwDk4MZuZAB6CuQAFQBlZCCAZiCg3WQvPiA)

The problem is that using `this` in the interface definition will not allow you to return just any instance of `Builder` but `this` current instance.

If you wanted, you could make `IBuilder` generic, which will allow you to define the return type of `build()` in the class definition:

```
interface IBuilder<T> {
  build(): T;
}

class Builder implements IBuilder<Builder> {
  public build() { // You can omit the type here, since it's defined through the interface.
    // return this;
    return new Builder(); // Both of these will work.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` simply refers to the current instance of the object. If the class `Builder` is instantiated, `this` will refer to `Builder` but that does mean it's always `Builder` since other classes can extend `Builder` and subsequently `this` will refer to the new instance type.

> Will it work the same as if method returned type of Builder?

Not necessarily,
see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=12&pln=13&pc=16#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICECuwA2ATaZAbwChlkAjbfACgEoAuZMAC2AGcBuZAeh+Sy4CUAPwkAviRIIccduwHVhyYAFsADjgiqI4BRiWFS5dZgo5gCSkvpNWHYmXLIoEMJighmbLk8mTpWXlkAGE2fEF8QggAD0gQPAVI5WNkU3NLayFbbwdU8ld3T1zfcn8pBAB7EHYwLKioZABeZBAIAHdFIWh6ADoqbLpOEj5ncgA9MSqauoRwvGTCFrbOsKFFqD6B2iGR-jHJkiA)